# select subset of column in IBM DB2

Tags: sql, database, select, db2, ibm-db2

I am not being able to perform select query on a subset of columns of a database in IBM DB2.

```
select * from user
```

This works. But

```
select username from user
```

doesn't work. Here's the screenshot.[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`username` is a reserved word. The "proper" solution would probably be to have a column name that isn't a reserved word, such as `user_name`. If changing the column name isn't an option, you could use double-quotes (`"`) to escape it:

```
SELECT "username" FROM user
```

Comment: And if you quote it,  case matters.   "username"  is not the same as "USERNAME"

Comment: "username" is not a reserved word. However, as @Charles indicates, the column was apparently created in lowercase, so now you have to quote it each time you reference it (as well as `"password"` and `"admin"` columns).